# OpsWorks Django Deployment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am trying to deploy a Django application using AWS OpsWorks. I'm brand spanking new to any sort of DevOps work, so I'm having considerable difficulties.

I am trying to use [this cookbook](https://github.com/alecpm/opsworks-web-python/tree/master/opsworks_deploy_python) to automate my deployments. I need Python3.4, so I modified a few things in the cookbook. Right now during the deploy hook, I am getting an error from the following code:

```
    # install requirements
  requirements = Helpers.django_setting(deploy, 'requirements', node)
  if requirements
    Chef::Log.info("Installing using requirements file: #{requirements}")
    pip_cmd = ::File.join(deploy["venv"], 'bin', 'pip')
    execute "#{pip_cmd} install --source=#{Dir.tmpdir} -r #{::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], 'current', requirements)}" do
      cwd ::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], 'current')
      user deploy[:user]
      group deploy[:group]
      environment 'HOME' => ::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], 'shared')
    end
  else
    Chef::Log.debug("No requirements file found")
  end
```

The error reports:

```
STDERR: /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141216163306_33300020141216163306/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.4.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:147:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /srv/www/django/current (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I get that this code is trying to install requirements from my requirements.txt file, but what is up with the `tmp` directory and the `current` directory? Clearly there is no `current` directory created when I do my deployment. What is the file structure generally like for code being pulled into OpsWorks from a deploy? Moreover, how might I go about finding a fix for this error?

I've been reading through documentation on Chef, OpsWorks, KitchenCI, Berksfile, and other technologies for days just feeling swamped by everything in the world of DevOps. I just want to get my application running!

**EDIT**

Custom json is:

```
{
    "deploy" : { 
        "django" : {
            "django_settings_template" : null,
            "django_settings_file" : "settings.py",
            "django_collect_static" : "true",
            "python_major_version" : "3.4",
            "venv_options" : "--python=$(which python3.4) --no-site-packages",
        "custom_type" : "django"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no current directory it's because it wasn't created during the deploy. Your script actually does reference that directory.

This block of code below is where you are having an error. If you refer to the documentation on the execute resource block https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html you'll see that if you don't provide a command to the execute resource then the name of the block will be what command is executed. So in your case you are generating the path to your pip command via Ruby's file.join so pip_cmd should be something like /usr/bin/pip and then the name of the block is the command which should be something like

```
#Mind you I'm not sure if the /tmp dir is correct, but if not it might also be the chef tmp directory
/usr/bin/pip install --source=/tmp -r /srv/www/django/current/requirements
```

Now in the resource you have the cwd attribute, which is the "current working directory" or the directory in which the command is executed. So when this command is executed it's being executed in /srv/www/django/current

```
pip_cmd = ::File.join(deploy["venv"], 'bin', 'pip')
execute "#{pip_cmd} install --source=#{Dir.tmpdir} -r #{::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], 'current', requirements)}" do
  cwd ::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], 'current')
  user deploy[:user]
  group deploy[:group]
  environment 'HOME' => ::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], 'shared')
end
```

Now without knowing a bit more about your deployment I can't really tell you how to fix it without knowing a bit more about your deployment. Can you post your actual cookbook code so we can see how you are using this cookbook to deploy your code?

```
{
  'deploy': {
    'django': {
                       'repository': 'Your github URL',
                       'revision': 'your revision number'
                       },
               }
}
```

Comment: After doing a bit more digging it appears that my code is not being deployed to SCM. The cookbook that I am using can be found at this repo: https://github.com/alecpm/opsworks-web-python/tree/master/opsworks_deploy_python I am getting a message at line 196 in the `python_base_deploy.rb`definition that no scm repository is set... I am, however, setting a Bitbucket repository for my application in the OpsWorks console, and deploy[:my_app][:scm] is being set correctly.

Comment: @rfj001 so then does your deployment setup look like the usage example on the github page? Can you post that?

Comment: You mean the custom deployment JSON I am sending to the stack?

Comment: Yes your JSON as denoted at the bottom of https://github.com/alecpm/opsworks-web-python/tree/master/opsworks_deploy_python you are using that right?

Comment: You are missing your SCM information in that. Refer to the example at the bottom of the github page for the exact keys, but I'll edit my post to add it in for you if you aren't sure what I mean.